# Select five random cards objects from the deck

Tags: java, arrays, constructor

Im trying to make an array in order to store 52 card objects into a "deck".
because i need both the string suit and the int value to be stored in the array i was going to try and use the constructor as the array type and it seems to work. I just wanted to know in using this method will my Card array work like a normal array. will i be able to use the built in methods on this array.

```js
public class Card {
  
  String suit;
  int value;
  
  public Card(String s, int v) {
    suit = s;
    value = v;
  }
}

public class Driver {
  
  Card[] deck = new Card[52];
}
```

Comment: In Englsh we capitalize the word "I". Also, check your language tag.

Comment: i don't really see how the fact that i is not capitalized is relevant to this question but ok.

Comment: Details matter, in coding and in communication.  When we see sloppy communication, we assume sloppy coding.

Comment: *Will my Card array work like a normal array?*  Yes.  You need to be careful when doing an array copy.  You'll copy the instance values, but not the underlying String and int.  This is called a shallow copy.

Comment: It is not directly relevant, but it is indirectly relevant because I assume you don't want future visitors to the site to think you are either don't know or don't care to write correct English. This is not a chatroom or an SMS message. It's not that hard. For second language speakers, it's taught the first time you learn the word "I". It's a quick press of the shift key.

Comment: I understand the importance of using correct English in the correct setting but I did assume that any complaints about my post would be directed toward my coding because that is what the question was about. What I don't understand is why you felt the need to nitpick the fact that I was not capatalized, ignore the fact that there were many other errors, and then not even attempt to offer any relevant advice as to my problem. I'm not saying you have to help only that it seems strange that you decided to give me a lesson on English when the question is about whether or not my array is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure this is Javascript and not Java?

If you make your class static:

```
public static class Driver {
```

You will be able to access your array using

```
Driver.deck.length();
```

or any other built in array functions